# Use custom Javascript files with imports in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 12 and I wanted to use custom JavaScript files in one of my ts components. To get this working I understood I need to add my custom.js file to the "Scripts" section in the angular.json and declare this in my ts component:

My custom.js file

```
function test() {
      alert("Hello!");

}
```

In the app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
declare function test(): void;

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
....
...
test();
```

and in the angular.json file i added the path to my custom.js

```
.....
   "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/custom.js"]
.....
```

This works fine and the alert message is displayed correctly when de app is served.

Let say now I want to use some Javascript library in my custom.js file, for example "sharp":

```
import {sharp} from "sharp";

function test() {
  alert("Hello!");
  const image = sharp("file.jpg");
}
```

Now when I serve the app via the "ng s", I can see the following error in the console of my browser:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This points to the "import {sharp} from "sharp"" line of my custom.js file of course.

I have alreayd tried to:

- add "type":"module" in the package.json but it did not solve the problem.
- install the sharp dependency via "npm i --save @types/sharp", but it did not help.
- add a "module.exoprts" in the custom.js file, but this also did not help.

My question is then the following:

where and how in my Angular project should I declare the need/use of the sharp library in order to let my custom.js work?

Thanks

Comment: try `const sharp = require("sharp")`

Answer (score 0):

To import another js file into another js `sharp.js` should export function `sharp()` and `test.js` should `import { sharp } from './main.js';`. Then test can use `sharp()` and your Angulr project is only using declared function `test()`. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file.php

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this does not work in Angular

Answer (score -1):

First, export the function `test.`

```js
export function test() {
  alert('custom js');
}
```

Import it into your app.component.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as yourlib from 'src/custom.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor(){
   yourlib.test();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this do not solve the problem when using "import" in the custom.js file